# set layout on top left of the JPanel instead of center

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Say I have a GridLayout in a JPanel, if my layout isn't big enought to fill the whole JPanel, it will auto align it at the center of ther JPanel like:
[image]

But I want my layout to align it on top left of the JPanel like:
[image]

so my component will start on top left of the panel, is there any method to do it?

Comment: @AhYong Probably you mean GridBagLayout?

Comment: can you set FlowLayout into JPanel will automatically set as per your requiremenyt

Comment: Use GridBagLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Add your gridLayoutPanel to another panel i.e. subPanel. Set this subPanel layout to the flow layout like `subPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT))`. Than set your main panel's layout to BorderLayout. And add your subPanel panel to the `NORTH` position of the main panel.

Example code:

```
JPanel subPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
subPanel.add(gridLayoutPanel);

mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
mainPanel.add(subPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: Bad idea. `BorderLayout` will provide horizontal stretching of component. `FlowLayout` would be better.

Comment: I changed my design. Now using `FlowLayout` in `BorderLayout`

Answer (score 0):

> it will auto align it at the center of ther JPanel like:

Sounds like you are using a GridBagLayout on the main panel and this is the default behaviour unless you use the GridBagConstraints to control this behaviour.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on How to Use GridBagLayout, especially the section on using the weightx/y constraints. Setting these constraints correctly will prevent the panel from centering itself.